# tabularx column width not behaving as expected

Tags: tables, itemize, tabularx

I'm trying to reproduce the following tabular design as close as possible:

[image]

This is what I have right now:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X X X X X}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{|Y|}{Width 1/2} & \multicolumn{3}{Y|}{Width 1/2} \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{|X|}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1
                \item Item 2
                \item Item 3
            \end{itemize}
        } & \multicolumn{3}{X|}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1
                \item Item 2
                \item Item 3
            \end{itemize}
        } \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{6}{|Y|}{Width 1} \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{6}{|X|}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1
                \item Item 2
                \item Item 3
            \end{itemize}
        } \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|Y|}{Width 1/3} & \multicolumn{2}{Y|}{Width 1/3} & \multicolumn{2}{Y|}{Width 1/3} \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|Y|}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1
                \item Item 2
                \item Item 3
            \end{itemize}
        } & \multicolumn{2}{Y|}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1
                \item Item 2
                \item Item 3
            \end{itemize}
        } & \multicolumn{2}{Y|}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1
                \item Item 2
                \item Item 3
            \end{itemize}
        } \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

However I end up with this:

- The column width is not working
- Text is not vertically centered
- I'm not sure if the text in the cells will linebreak

How can I improve the result? I'm close to using Word/Excel for this...

[image: Result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slight improvement with vertical centring of the cell contents and a title:

```
\documentclass[12pt,x11names, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{%
\setlist[itemize, 1,2]{label=\color{LightSteelBlue3}\textbullet, leftmargin = 0.8em,nosep, before =\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}\RaggedRight, after=\leavevmode\vspace{\dimexpr-\baselineskip + \extrarowheight\relax},}%itemsep=1pt, , topsep=0pt,
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
    \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\cellcolor{LightSteelBlue3}\sffamily\bfseries\color{white}Title}\\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{|p{\dimexpr(\textwidth-3\arrayrulewidth-4\tabcolsep)/2\relax}|}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1
                \item Item 2
                \item Item 3
            \end{itemize}
        } & \multicolumn{3}{|p{\dimexpr(\textwidth-3\arrayrulewidth-4\tabcolsep)/2\relax}|}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1
                \item Item 2
                \item Item 3
            \end{itemize}
        } \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Width 1} \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{6}{|p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\arrayrulewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}|}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1
                \item Item 2
                \item Item 3
            \end{itemize}
        } \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Width 1/3} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Width 1/3} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Width 1/3} \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr(\textwidth-4\arrayrulewidth-6\tabcolsep)/3\relax}|}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1
                \item Item 2
                \item Item 3
            \end{itemize}
        } & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr(\textwidth-4\arrayrulewidth-6\tabcolsep)/3\relax}|}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1
                \item Item 2
                \item Item 3
            \end{itemize}
        } & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr(\textwidth-4\arrayrulewidth-6\tabcolsep)/3\relax}|}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1
                \item Item 2
                \item Item 3
            \end{itemize}
        } \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You really don't want `tabularx` here as you know in advance how wide you want the columns to be. Your attempt failed as `tabularx` essentially does some calculations and then replaces every `X` by `p{x}` for some width x (the same value in every case) but you want cells that are half, full or third width.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{document}
\noindent
    \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Title}\\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{|p{\dimexpr(\textwidth-3\arrayrulewidth-4\tabcolsep)/2\relax}|}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1
                \item Item 2
                \item Item 3
            \end{itemize}
        } & \multicolumn{3}{|p{\dimexpr(\textwidth-3\arrayrulewidth-4\tabcolsep)/2\relax}|}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1
                \item Item 2
                \item Item 3
            \end{itemize}
        } \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Width 1} \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{6}{|p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\arrayrulewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}|}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1
                \item Item 2
                \item Item 3
            \end{itemize}
        } \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Width 1/3} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Width 1/3} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Width 1/3} \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr(\textwidth-4\arrayrulewidth-6\tabcolsep)/3\relax}|}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1
                \item Item 2
                \item Item 3
            \end{itemize}
        } & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr(\textwidth-4\arrayrulewidth-6\tabcolsep)/3\relax}|}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1
                \item Item 2
                \item Item 3
            \end{itemize}
        } & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr(\textwidth-4\arrayrulewidth-6\tabcolsep)/3\relax}|}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1
                \item Item 2
                \item Item 3
            \end{itemize}
        } \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```